# How to have my customized extension?

Tags: htaccess, url, 301-redirect, iis, filenames

I have recently found a .htaccess trick in which I can remove file extension from the URL, `example.com/file.html` looks like example.com/file

Now my humor says that I can replace any extension to my own, I want `example.com/file.htm`l to be `example.com/file.syml`

Is this possible?? or I am just daydreaming?? If this isn't possible then how does Microsoft uses MSPX, I think MS stands Microsoft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AddType directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) lets you specify what [MIME type](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full)(not entirely a complete list) a given file extension should be processed as. To make an arbitrary extension be processed as HTML:

```
AddType text/html .whatever
```

Note that there's generally very little reason to do this sort of thing, and it mostly just introduces maintenance work.